# How to have custom list labels on R ggplot figure x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have custom values on x-axis from the list `dates` which contains dates in string format.
I am not so interested in melting the data with `mpg` because main columns have the data structure where value is integer and I cannot have there Posixct dates.

```
   Vars         variable     value
1:    1              Leo       164
...
```

Code which current output in Fig. 1.

```
library('ggplot2')    
str(mpg)

dates <- c("1.1.2017", "1.2.2017", "1.3.2017", "2.4.2017", "10.5.2017", "12.5.2017", "13.5.2017")

# TODO how to have here custom values on x-axis from dates?
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class, y = hwy)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

You cannot simply have `x = dates` because `dates` does not belong to `mpg`.

Fig. 1 Current output with default x-labels

[image]

Expected output: those 7 dates on the x-axis of the figure.

R: 3.4.0 (backports)
OS: Debian 8.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class, y = hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = dates)
```

If you want to maintain the values in the axis, use `scale_x_continuous` instead, for istance the following which keeps the tick values forthe y-axis

```
scale_y_continuous("Y Axis Title")
```

Comment: the axis is discrete so use `scale_x_discrete("Dates",labels = dates)`

Comment: Which values are you not trying to affect? The axis title? The tick mark labels? Something else?

Comment: you can manipulate the appearance of the y-axis with `+ 
  scale_y_continuous("Y Axis Title" , lim = c(20,40))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145050/discussion-between-johnckane-and-leo-leopold-hertz-).

Comment: Hi, the solution is just `scale_y_continuous("Y Axis Title")` to maintain the values at the axis with the `continous` option there.